# how to get the area and perimeter of geometric shapes to work?

Tags: c++

calculate the area and 
perimeter of geometric shapes. First the user is asked to enter a letter representing 
the shape. We use C for circle, R for rectangle and  S for square.
After the user chooses the shape, the program prompts for the appropriate 
dimensions of the shape accordingly.  For instance, if the user has chosen a square, 
the program will ask for a side. If it’s a circle, the program will ask for radius. If 
it’s a rectangle, it will ask for length and width. 
Upon receiving the appropriate dimensions, the program will calculate the area and 
the perimeter of the requested shape and print it on the screen. And again, the code 
will ask for another letter. If the user enters ‘Q’ the program terminates.

One run of the program will look like this:

```
Please Enter Shape (C: Circle, S: Square, R: Rectangle Q:quit)
>S
Please enter the side of the square 
> 8
The area is 64 and the perimeter is 32
Please Enter Shape (C: Circle, S: Square, R: Rectangle Q:quit)
>R 
Please enter the width of the rectangle 
> 5 
Please enter the length of the rectangle
> 7  
The area is 35 and the perimeter is 24
Please Enter Shape (C: Circle, S: Square, R: Rectangle Q:quit)
```

This is what I have done so far, but **don't know why I can't get it to ask for The side of the square when I press S.**

what I did get is:

```
Please Enter Shape (C: Circle, S: Square, R: Rectangle Q:quit)
```

and what ever I enter except for Q it repeats the same question. Q just stops but any other  charter entered will ask for `Please Enter Shape (C: Circle, S: Square, R: Rectangle Q:quit)`

what is going on ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //clear the screen.
    //clrscr();
    //declare variable type int
    char shape = 'N'; //none
    int area, perimeter;
    while( shape != 'Q' )
    {
        cout<<"Please Enter Shape (C: Circle, S: Square, R: Rectangle Q:quit) >"<<endl;
        //get shape choice
        cin>>shape;

        if( shape == 'C' )
        {
        int radius;
        //Circle, radius
        cout<<"Please enter the radius >"<<endl;
        }
        else if( shape == 'S' )
        {
        int side;
        //Input the side
        cout<<"Please enter the side of the square >"<<endl;
        //Square, side
        cin>>side;
        //calculate perimeter and save it in 'peri'
        perimeter=4*side;
        //show the output 'perimeter'
        cout<<"Perimeter of square is "<<perimeter<<endl;
        }
        else if( shape == 'R' )
        {
        int width,length;
        //Rectangle, width,length
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Are you entering 's' or 'S'?

Comment: As @ScottMermelstein said, one possible reason for this may be that you enter the option in lower case whereas the code is expecting uppercase.

Comment: Yes you are write I had to enter upper case. but how can I make it ask for area first than the perimeter?

Comment: does it work for other characters 'C', 'R'?. A better option can be to convert shape to uppercase.

Comment: Also how do I make that for Circle since when I put in C it gives me
C
Please enter the radius >
Please Enter Shape (C: Circle, S: Square, R: Rectangle Q:quit) >
and I can't ask for its radius just jumps out

Comment: Re area first then perimeter, this seems to be a common question today.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452303/how-to-calculate-area-and-perimeter-so-i-can-print-in-same-printf/19452538#19452538 even though its in C, you may get the basics of how to use variables from it.

Comment: Does not work for C or R

Comment: Ok.  Time to vote for close.  Why doesn't it work for C or R?  Because **you haven't coded it to do so.**

Comment: It would be a good idea to use switch over the multiple if-else block.

Answer (score 2):

Change your conditionals from

```
if (shape == 'R')
```

To

```
if (shape == 'R' || shape == 'r')
```

Or, change them to all be 1 case before you test:

```
cin >> shape;
shape = std::toupper(shape);
if (shape == 'R') // already know it is between A-Z, so we can just check the uppercase
```

Comment: thanks that works but I have a problem with finding the circle and Rectangle area and parameter.

Comment: also how would I make it ask for the are of the square since I do get the parameter for the square?
Please Enter Shape (C: Circle, S: Square, R: Rectangle Q:quit) >
s
Please enter the side of the square >
2
Perimeter of square is 8

Comment: In the code you posted, you are not asking for those parameters (that is, there is no `cin >> radius;` statement - same with the rectangle block).  Just like you did for the square, you have to ask for the parameters you want to work with.

Comment: You don't need to ask for any more information for the square, you just have to compute the area and display it.  I take it this is for a homework assignment?